# Debugging: How to see returned value of function

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-number-picker

I have this class and I want to see what is the current value of view.getValue() when I scroll the number picker, I put a breakpoint inside if but I'm unable to see its value

```
public class ClsCallbackBottomSheet implements NumberPicker.OnScrollListenr{


@Override
public void onScrollStateChange(NumberPicker view, int scrollState) {

    if (scrollState == 0) {
        ClsBottomSheet.tv.setText(ClsBottomSheet.values[view.getValue()]);
    }
 }
```

[image: getting these values]

Comment: Are you somehow using Visual Studio to write Java code? If not, please remove the `visual-studio-debugging` tag

Comment: Did you check view.getValue() using dynamic execution that i have mentioned in my answer

Comment: yesy I checked in debug mode, not available in normal mode

Comment: Actually this control is available only in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = view.getValue();
ClsBottomSheet.tv.setText(ClsBottomSheet.values[value]);
```

Either separate them like that, or step into the getValue function

Comment: I'm stepping into but its not taking me to getvalue

Comment: click on the image, its when first time break point takes focus, if Im stepping into it first taking me to numberpicker set max and set min method, after that in textview, but never getvalue

Answer (score 0):

If you are in debug mode you can get method or variable value by dynamic execution. Please check below screen shot. Here i have marked a control it will enable in debug mode, and you can execute your code by using this option. Hope this will help you.[image]

Comment: yes it workes, but number picker is freezed so i can only see current value, can't see beyond this like dynamic